# Get reference to ~30 EditTexts/SeekBars and give them individual listeners

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to android development and I currently have a simple swipe-tablayout with 5 fragments, each of the fragments has a vertical LinearLayout with about ~20-30 horizontal LinearLayouts with a TextView, (SeekBar) and EditText/Switch.

Layoutsnippet:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="Setting1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:max="50"
        android:progress="25" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="Setting2"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:max="50"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:progress="25" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there any way thats less tedious than doing "findViewById" for every single EditText/Seekbar/Switch?

Also I would like to give all EditTexts a FocusChangeListener, all SeekBars a SeekBarChangeListener, so that the EditTexts text mirrors the progress value of SeekBar and the SeekBar reacts to EditText input.

I want to avoid writing:

```
    sw1 = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    sb1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
    sb1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean 
        fromUser) {
            et1.setText(Integer.toString(progress));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
    et1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            sb1.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString()));
        }
    });
```

over and over again.

Would really appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into [custom views](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html). You can encapsulate your logic into a compound view and reuse it multiple times.